# Use jekyll variable inside replace filter

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have an RSS template in Jekyll as below:

```
---
layout: nil
---
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <title>{{ site.title }}</title>
 <link href="{{ site.url }}/feed.atom" rel="self"/>
 <link href="{{ site.url }}/"/>
 <updated>{{ site.time | date_to_xmlschema }}</updated>
 <id>{{ site.url }}/</id>
 <author>
   <name>{{ site.author.name }}</name>
   <email>{{ site.author.email }}</email>
 </author>
 {% for post in site.posts limit:20 %}
 <entry>
   <title>{{ post.title }}</title>
   <link href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}"/>
   <updated>{{ post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}</updated>
   <id>{{ site.url }}{{ post.id }}</id>
   <content type="html">{{ post.content | replace:'src="/assets','src="http://example.com/assets' | xml_escape }}</content>
 </entry>
 {% endfor %}
</feed>
```

Now, I want `http://example.com` (currently hard-coded) to be replaced with `{{ site.url }}` variable. I have tried numerous ways, but am unable to achieve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Part of the answer was in the question :

```
{{ post.content | replace:'src="/assets','src="http://example.com/assets' | xml_escape | replace: 'http://example.com', site.url }}
```

Comment: Please re-read my question. The url is currently hard-coded. I need to change it to a variable instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry for the down vote.